Cómo actualizar el front desde el back en un aspx al descargar un archivo
tengo un aspx que mediante un botón manda un formulario y llama un script para mostrar un spinner en el evento submit y en el lado del codebehind obtiene la información, genera un excel y lo descarga del lado del cliente y llama un script para ocultar el botón.
El problema es que no puedo ocultar el spinner y descargar al mismo tiempo. Si comento la descarga si oculta el spinner, si la descomento el spinner se queda. Así está el código, espero alguien tenga una idea de que sucede y cómo solucionarlo sin utilizar AJAX (Son muchos cambios para múltiples secciones similares y el tiempo es limitado)?
Front:
HTML
<form name="form1" id="form1" runat="server" onsubmit="muestraSpinner();" > 
<asp:Button runat="server" ID="BtnDescargaExpro" Text="Expro" class="button" Style="margin-left: 15%; margin-top: 2%" OnClick="BtnDescarga_Click" />
</form>
<div id="containerspinner" runat="server" class="ocultar">
        <i id="spinner" class="fa fa-spinner"></i>
    </div>

JS
 function muestraSpinner() {
        document.getElementById('containerspinner').classList.remove('ocultar');       
    }
function ocultaSpinner() {
        document.getElementById('containerspinner').classList.add('ocultar');
    }

CSS
#containerspinner.ocultar {
    top: -100%;
    opacity: 0;
}

Back:
protected void BtnDescarga_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    using (ExcelPackage ep = new ExcelPackage())
    {
        /// Se crea el excel

        ScriptManager.RegisterStartupScript(Page, GetType(), "oculta_spinner", "<script>ocultaSpinner();</script>", false);
        /// Si comento a partir de aquí si realiza el llamado a la función "ocultaSpinner()"
        /// Si no lo hago la función nunca se llama y el spinner nunca se oculta
        Response.Clear();
        Response.Buffer = true;
        Response.Charset = "";
        Response.ContentType = "application/vnd.openxmlformats- officedocument.spreadsheetml.sheet";
        Response.AddHeader("content-disposition", $"attachment;filename={nombrearchivo}.xlsx");
        using (MemoryStream MyMemoryStream = new MemoryStream())
        {
            paquete.SaveAs(MyMemoryStream);
            MyMemoryStream.WriteTo(Response.OutputStream);
            Response.Flush();
            HttpContext.Current.ApplicationInstance.CompleteRequest();
            Response.Close();
        } 
    }
}                                 


Prueba agregar antes del Response.Clear() un Response.Flush()

Ya había intentado la sugerencia de @Yussef y no me funcionó, al final decidí realizar la petición por AJAX y al finalizarla cerrar el spinner.

agrega el código de lo que realizaste para que sea de ayuda a la comunidad, revisar [answer]
